# Get a JLabel to be positioned under mouse?

Tags: java, user-interface, mouse

I am making a mouse event listener and handler. I have something like this:

```
JLabel status = new JLabel("I can change");
```

And using my MouseListener, I am changing the text of the JLabel, based on given conditions. I can easily keep this JLabel in one place, for example at the bottom of the window, like this:

```
add(status, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
```

But what I want to do is to take that JLabel, and display it directly under the mouse. This would be similar to a

```
.setToolTipText
```

method, but I cannot use that, as I am moving the mouse over an image within a JDialog, which is in grid layout format. Please explain how to keep the changing JLabel directly under the mouse, just like .setToolTipText.

There are two images within GridLayout, which is in a JDialog:

```
    JDialog giraffewindow = new JDialog();
            Icon giraffe = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("giraffe.png"));
            Icon windows = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("windows.png"));

            giraffewindow.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
            giraffewindow.add(new JLabel (windows));
            giraffewindow.add(new JLabel (giraffe));
```

Thank you so much for the time you are taking for reading this, I really appreciate the effort you are putting into helping a fellow programmer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this, you need to set the `JLabel`'s parent container (the `JDialog`)'s layout to an absolute layout. This will let you set the label's position manually.

To set the layout to null:

```
myPanel.setLayout(null);
```

Then, to set the label's position, call the `setBounds` method:

```
status.setBounds(int xPos, int yPos, int width, int height);
```

In your case, you would chance `xPos` and `yPos` to the mouse's coordinates whenever the mouse is moved. You might also want to add some constant to the coords if you need a bit of an offset.

For example:

```
    giraffewindow.add(status);

    giraffewindow.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

        @Override
        public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
            status.setBounds(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), labelWidth,
                    labelHeight);
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {}
    });
```

---

Edit:

I just learned that it is possible to still set the bounds on a non-absolute layout, such as `GridLayout`. I had assumed only absolute layouts supported that, but a quick test proved my wrong. However, adding another component to the `GridLayout` seems to mess things up a bit. I will provide another update when I resolve this

---

Edit 2:

In order to have the `JLabel` not mess up the layout, you have two options:

1. Use a `GlassPane`. Think of a glass pane as a sheet of glass covering the components underneath of it. By adding the `JLabel` to the glass pane instead of the `JDialog`, we avoid messing up the layout. See below:

   ```
   JPanel glass = ((JPanel) giraffewindow.getGlassPane());
   glass.setVisible(true);
   glass.add(status);

   glass.addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionListener() {

       @Override
       public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent evt) {
           status.setBounds(evt.getX(), evt.getY(), labelWidth,
                   labelHeight);
       }

       @Override
       public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent arg0) {
       }
   });
   ```

The problem with this approach is that it intercepts all mouse events, meaning that JButtons and such underneath of the glass will not be. Some possible work-arounds include having the glass look at every mouse event and decide if it should pass that event on to another component. See [here for an example](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html) on how to use this concept.

2. The other possibility is with `JLayeredPane`s. Note: I have next to no experience with `JLayeredPane`s, so there may be small inaccuracies here and there. Basically, a `JLayeredPane` allows you to layer components on top of one another. For your purposes, I would create two layers: One to contain a new `JPanel` with a `GridLayout` containing the images, and one to contain the `status` moving label. See below:

   ```
   JLayeredPane layeredPane = new JLayeredPane();
   {
       JPanel imagePanel = new JPanel();
       layeredPane.add(imagePanel);
       layeredPane.setLayer(imagePanel, 0);
       imagePanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
       {
           imagePanel.add(new JLabel (windows));
           imagePanel.add(new JLabel (giraffe));
       }

       layeredPane.add(status);
       layeredPane.setLayer(status, 1);
   }
   giraffewindow.add(layeredPane);
   ```

Unfortunately this suffers the same problems. You can surround the status label in a `JPanel`, and add the mouse listener to this panel instead, but then no mouse actions will be passed to any buttons beneath. Or, you can simply add the mouse listener to the main `JDialog`, which means that cursing over a component that captures mouse events, such as a `JButton`, will stop the `status` label from moving.

Comment: If I set it to null, will i still have my grid layout?

Comment: Sorry, I missed that in the question. Is the JDialog's layout the GridLayout?

Comment: Yes, there are two images in GridLayout within the JDialog

Comment: SInce the code is not formatted properly in comment section, I will edit my question to put it in

Comment: I also tried to do your method, by changing the coordinates of the JLabel to correspond to the coordinates of the mouse, I will post that in the following comment. Note that I did this without changing the formatting to null. After doing this, I got errors saying the method getX is undefined for the type ActionEvent.

Comment: int xPos = event.getX();

Comment: int yPos = event.getY();

Comment: status.setBounds(int xPos, int yPos, width, height);

Comment: See edit. You can't use an ActionListener, you need a MouseMotionListener

Comment: Logically this should run, but for some reason, in the actual window, the JLabel is just on the side, and it does not change at all! I understand the code and advice you have given me and have incorporated it in my code, and it should work, but it isn't working. Do you know why? I think it is because of my object status, I have to instantiate it twice. My mousemotionlistener is in a different file than my other stuff, and so unless I put JLabel status = new JLabel("I can change"); in **each** file, I get the error: status cannot be resolved. I think this has to do with scope or something.Help!

Comment: I would just like to say that I really appreciate your help, and it is because of amazing people like you that beginners can strive! I will mark you best answer and like your answer as soon as I figure out this problem, which might have to do with scope. Thanks

Comment: I'm working on adding a bunch of content to my answer, but it sounds like you might want to make that JLabel a member variable, or class scope (Declared outside of any method). This way, you can access it from another class by using `objectContainingTheLabel.status`. See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html) and [here](http://www.java-made-easy.com/variable-scope.html) for help

Comment: If you create a new JLabel in each file, they will simply be completely different JLabels that happen to contain the same text. They have nothing to do with eachother, and won't work as you want

Comment: I know, and am working on only creating one JLabel, that both files can use without getting the error that I posted. I have looked at your links, but I cannot add a modifier to my object. How should I work around this problem then?

Comment: I don't follow what you're saying, but the easiest and cleanest way of doing this is simply by keeping the listener in the same class. Since this isn't really a listener we'll be reusing, you're fine simply doing an inline anonymous definition like in my example. Why are you trying to keep it in a different class?

Comment: After putting everything into the same class, it still doesn't work. Would you like me to send you the full code?

Comment: @Rich go ahead and post in the question. Or, paste it into a site such as PasteBin and link to it in the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/87840/discussion-between-rich-and-thewalkingcactus).

Comment: By posting it in chat, it retains it's properly formatted state

Answer (score 1):

> but I cannot use that - setToolTipText()

Why?

> I am moving the mouse over an image

You are moving the mouse over a JLabel which supports tool tip text.

If you want the tooltip to move with the mouse you just need to override the `getToolTipLocation(...)` method as demonstrated below:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.plaf.*;
import javax.swing.UIManager.*;


public class ToolTipPanel extends JPanel
{
    public ToolTipPanel()
    {
        setPreferredSize( new Dimension(200, 200) );
        setToolTipText("");
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor( Color.red );
        g.fillRect(0, 0, 100, 200);
        g.setColor( Color.blue );
        g.fillRect(100, 0, 100, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getX() < 100)
            return "red";
        else
            return "blue";
    }

    @Override
    public Point getToolTipLocation(MouseEvent e)
    {
        Point p = e.getPoint();
        p.y += 15;

        return p;
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI()
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("SSCCE");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new ToolTipPanel());
        frame.setLocationByPlatform( true );
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible( true );
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
        {
            public void run()
            {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The other approach would be to use a JXLayer to paint text as your move your mouse. Check out the `Responding to Events` example from the Swing tutorial on [How to Decorate Components with the JLayer Class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/jlayer.html) for an example to get your started.